# Django: How to inherit and query related field

Tags: django, django-models, django-inheritance

I've been searching for an answer to this for a while. How can I add a field from one model to a related model and query the related models data.

Here is an example: One Person has many Jobs.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    PersonId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')

class Job(models.Model):
    JobId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    JobName = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    Person = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column='PersonId')

    def _fullname(self):
        return self.Person.FirstName + " " + self.Person.LastName
    fullname = property(_fullname)
```

**The code above does work!**

```
jobs = Job.objects.select_related()
for job in jobs:
    print job.fullname
```

Now I think I have a different problem. Getting the Django Rest Framework to serialize these additional properties. Time for a new post.

Now what I want to be able to do is query jobs and get the related person data as well as have the person fields on the job. This way when I query jobs I can use job.FirstName. I basically want to make a shortcut to the Person fields from the Job. This is a bit like the Job is inheriting the fields of the Person.

An expected site effect of this would be when serializing the Job as json for a rest resource the result would include the Person field data.

I'm coming from a .Net C# background. Now since I'm using Python/Django I have no idea how to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Example of queryset which gets filtered list of *Job* objects:

```
joblist = Job.objects.filter(statement1,statement2...)
```

You can access to persons associated by [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) with Job objects in this way

```
for j in joblist:    
    print j.Person.FirstName, j.Person.LastName
```

If you exactly need all related objects on every *Job* record you should use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) queryset

```
joblist = Job.objects.select_related().filter(statement1,statement2...)
```

**Serialization:** 
You can use [natural_keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys), but it's limited with DB constraints. Or you can use [Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) and define a Handler which will produce nested JSON.

Notice, you dont have to make AutoField for every model, it's specified by convention and can be reached at model_instance.id.

Also I recommend you to follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) conventions.

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond to both answers so I'm responding to the most recent. My question now is the same for both. Both of these answers require filtering the results. I want to be able to call Job.objects.all() and get the data for both models. I also understand that I can use job.Person.Firstname but that's also not what I asked. I want to know how to add the FirstName field to Job so I can access it directly. I want to be able to query and use just the Job. I want this so when I serialize this to json it's one job object and not a job object with a nested person object.

Comment: I have played with .select_related() and I'm still looking into this. This still doesn't solve my problem of reusing the related Person fields on Job. It does look like Job.objects.select_related() will pull the related data the way I was hoping for. Now how to reuse the fields.

Comment: I'm currently using Django Rest Framework for my rest/serialization. So far it's working well though it could use more documentation and examples. I have a lot to learn still.

Comment: This honestly is probably the easiest way to go. `select_related()` basically (if you squint real hard) gives you 'direct' access to the person's name through the same single query. However, I don't know what you are intending to do with the serialization so I don't understand your reasoning for whatever you are trying to accomplish.  Side question- are all the Jobs unique to one person? i.e. if there are 3 accountants, are the JobIds 1,2,3 all with the accountant JobName? That could be the case, but in my mind i see it probably being a M2M field, or having a Job FK in the Person model

Answer (score 0):

If you query your jobs with something like 
`job = Job.objects.get(personid=1)` you'll see that it pulls through the related fields too, it's voodoo behind the scenes. So essentially you can now do `job.person.firstname`, `job.person.lastname` etc...

Comment: I do know that this works but it's not what I want. I want to put the Person fields on the Job so that I only have one object to deal with. It simplifies coding as the project gets bigger. Instead of having to type job.person.firstname every time I use the job I instead put firstname in the Job and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it sounds like what you want.

Then a Job IS A Person, which, is what you're asking for. This is not abstract inheritance, so there will be two tables in your DB.

```
$> # This will dump the sql that's generated.
$> ./manage.py sql this_app
```

Job.FirstName will work.  Read up on [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).  You might evenautally need to use django-model-utils's ModelInheritance manager, which is quite nice.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    PersonId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')

class Job(Person):
    JobId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    JobName = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
```

Comment: Model inheritance isn't what I want either. What I have is a Person who can have many different jobs. Let's say in a job view I want to display the full name of the person doing the job. So I want to be able to query jobs and list all the jobs with the persons full name. I've edited this change into my original question using a Django property.